# Code Igniter querying wrong table - sessions

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am querying a table called 'users'. But it is not working, it is querying the sessions table instead.

The output of the show last query is:

```
SELECT * FROM (`sessions`)
WHERE `session_id` = '034594375ce4c6f3d1b3b95c5cfc5bed'
AND `user_agent` = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0'
```

I am "selecting users.* from users".

Why is it pulling from the sessions table?

The code for my query is here:

```
public function getByBlpIdSmallJoin($blp_id)    {
    $this->db->select('nlp_screenings.*,nlp_screenings.id as nlp_screening_id,screenings.*, screenings.id as screening_id, nlp_screenings.launched as nlp_screenings_launched, DATE_FORMAT(screenings.screening_time, "%c/%d/%Y") as screening_date, DATE_FORMAT(screenings.screening_time, "%h:%i %p") as the_screening_time', FALSE);
    $this->db->from($this->db_table_name);
    $this->db->join('screenings', 'nlp_screenings.screening_id=screenings.id');
    $this->db->join('blp', 'blp.id=nlp_screenings.blp_id');
    $this->db->where('blp_id', $blp_id);
    $this->db->where('archive', '0');
    $this->db->where('printed_pass', '0');
    $query = $this->db->get()->result();
    echo $this->db->last_query();

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell anything without looking at your code

Comment: What other code do you need?

Comment: The CodeIgniter model that is producing the SQL query in your question

Comment: You are showing us the result and not the code that is producing this result, the problem is in the code that is producing this result, so showing the result doesn't provide us any useful information to help.

Comment: What do you get if you do `var_dump($this->db->queries);`?  That should output the list of queries which have been ran